# Spring Boot & Zuul not honoring proxied favicon

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've tried a few different configurations to tell Zuul to use the favicon of my proxied web-server, but I've come up empty handed.  Here's what I have configured as of now on my Zuul server.

```
zuul.routes.favicon.path=/favicon.ico
zuul.routes.favicon.url=http://mycontentserver.com/favicon.ico
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
```

But the responses?

```
$ curl -sIL http://myzuulserver.com/favicon.ico
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Which should route to...

```
$ curl -sIL http://mycontentserver.com/favicon.ico
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Keeping the Spring MVC favicon enabled just returns the typical Spring icon.

Do I have something misconfigured here?  Am I misunderstanding how favicons work?

Comment: I actually needed `spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false` for a similar issue (zuul serving favicon instead of letting /** route handling it). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So spring cloud netflix zuul appends the path to the url. The 404 you are experiencing is from `mycontentserver.com` not zuul. It is asking for `http://mycontentserver.com/favicon.ico/favicon.ico`.

Set `zuul.routes.favicon.url=http://mycontentserver.com/`.